# Is there a list or exhaustive description of referrer parameters that the Android Market app sends to the referrer intent?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm handling `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` and getting everything just fine including custom referrers, but in my logs in addition to the referrers that I set myself, there are a number of entries like this:

```
utm_source=androidmarket&utm_medium=device&utm_campaign=downloads
utm_source=androidmarket&utm_medium=device&utm_campaign=search&utm_term=something
```

That's fine and clearly these are coming directly from the Android Market app, but I was wondering if there's a list somewhere which describes all of these different values (particularly the different values for utm_campaign) for the Android Market.

I'm not asking what `utm_campaign` is but rather what are all the values that the Android Market can generate for `utm_campaign` and what do each of them mean. (E.g. The search one is pretty obvious: someone searched for the term in `utm_term` using the Market app, and this app came up and was downloaded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an official list for these terms.

Unfortunately, the newer versions of the Android market client don't set this referrer string anymore. They do still set any specific user-generated string (market://details?id=PKGNAME&referrer=my_referrer), but none of the 'organic' search or browse strings anymore.
I hope this is a bug, as it was very valuable information for developers on how people discover your app, but only people from Google know whether this is the case.

EDIT: I filed an issue at the Android bugtracker for this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24119
Star that issue if you want to keep up to date whether this feature will be brought back.

Comment: Yeah, I never did find an official (or even unofficial semi-complete) list. I'm not sure what is going to happen with this feature as a whole anyway though as [it doesn't work on 3.1+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985775/dont-get-android-market-install-referrer-on-android-3-x/8512837#8512837)