# Android INSTALL_REFERRER and Google Play Store

Tags: android, installation, google-play, referrer

I played around with the INSTALL_REFERRER and everything works perfectly fine using adb, but not when my app is in the Google Play-Store.

My scenario is:

1) One library containing my BroadcastReceiver (package com.sm.android)
2) My app using the library (package de.sm.android)

In the AndroidManifest.xml-file of the app, the receiver-part looks like:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.sm.android.helper.ReferralReceiver"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

As said before, using adb I get the install-event, but when downloading the app from the store, I don't get the event. I build my url using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns, it looks like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.sm.riskulator&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dbanner%26utm_content%3D234124%26utm_campaign%3Dpromo and forwards correctly to my app.

Thanks in advance,
Sascha

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I thought this was now disabled as it was a security hole. i.e It allows code to run on a phone before the user initiates it.

**Update: Links for reference.**

https://nayaneshguptetechstuff.wordpress.com/2014/06/24/receiver-not-working-know-more-about-stopped-state-of-an-application/

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html 
(See **Launch controls on stopped applications**)

[Intercept INSTALL_REFERRER and then forward on to Google AnalyticsReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984036/intercept-install-referrer-and-then-forward-on-to-google-analyticsreceiver)

Comment: @Kuffs Can you provide a link which confirm this feature is disabled? Thanks

Comment: Is this still correct? Or was it ever? They keep posting new SDK versions for Google Analytics that rely on INSTALL_REFERRER. It seems very unlikely that it was disabled 3 years ago, unless, of course, it got re-enabled meanwhile?!? Are there any docs on any of this?

Comment: I just searched Google and updated the answer with some links I found.