# How to pass parameter from browser to mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm launching Android app from browser using intent. How can I pass parameter from browser to mobile app and how can I retrieve that parameter value in Android app. I'm using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

with Intent, can not it use putExtra and its correspond API to get some customized data? see [Intent::putExtra](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20int[]))

Comment: Actually I am using window.location in browser file to redirect/launch Mobile App.In window.location I am giving intent value like window.location=testapp://site.com?param1=value1.Now I want to retrieve this parameter in Mobile App.Help in this scenario.

Comment: sorry, i did not experience this before. i guess maybe you can getIntent in onResume(or onCreate) and try to see whether it is passed in by the data of intent( you can get it by getIntent().getData())

Comment: Actually I want to use authentication using external url in my Android Mobile App.I am opening that URL in Mobile browser.After successfully login, I want to set a flag in Mobile app.Can you tell me how to do this ?

Comment: can you please  check whether [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123955/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-message-from-an-android-browser-to-an-app) is what you need?