# how to grab referrer/campaign source from google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

from the very bottom of [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns). theres a URL generator which I can generate a link to my app on google play with a referrer. How can I extra that campaign source from google analytics?? I've been searching on google but still can't find the answer. i found someone saying that I should make a class which extends BroadcastReceiver, but I also found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817030/get-android-google-analytics-referrer-tag). by doing that, I won't be able to get GA work. GA is very powerful and I want to use it. All I need now is to extract a parameter which is the referrer/campaign source from GA. I also found that there are several getters under EasyTracker.getTracker(), like getAppId(), getAppInstallerId() and getTrackingId(), but none of them is documented. how do I know which ID getter belongs to which? 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Although referrer/campaign tutorial document is in GA(google analytics) document,You can get Referrer information and use it in your app without implementing GA, see: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-implement

```
<!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Just change the 3rd line to your custom BroadCastReceiver example:

```
<!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
<receiver android:name="com.xxx.Myapp.CustomReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Your custom BroadCastReceiver maybe:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver;

/*
 *  A simple Broadcast Receiver to receive an INSTALL_REFERRER
 *  intent and pass it to other receivers, including
 *  the Google Analytics receiver.
 */
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // get referrer info
     String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
    // do anything you want with referrer
     ......

    // When you're done, pass the intent to the Google Analytics receiver
    new CampaignTrackingReceiver().onReceive(context, intent);
  }
}
```