# Android referrer string returning only first param

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, referrer

When I setup a BroadcastReceiver for a referrer string like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3945100/2760406) and test the receiver like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6966718/2760406), the log for `String referrerString = extras.getString("referrer");` returns only the first param `utm_source=test_source` and nothing after the "&" concatenation.

Why when I user a string with "&" (e.g. `referrer=utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium...`) is only the first param returned, yet when I construct the params using the google style (e.g., `referrer=utm_source%3Dtest_source%26utm_medium%3Dtest_medium...`) the entire string is returned?